# selenium ide : click button with class on specific row in table

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I have an html table wich contain multiple lines.
At the end of each line, the last row contain multiple button. I would like to click on the remove button of the first line.

I tried this Xpath code but the element in not located :
There is a mistake somewhere in my xpath query :

```
//table[@id='tableTest']/tbody/tr[8]/td[8]/a[@class="remove"]
```

Comment: Can you provide the html code for your table?

Comment: It is not actually useful information without `HTML` code for required element

Comment: @wawanopoulos If it is the first row, I'd assume the index for `tr` should be `[1]`

Comment: ^ and, probably, `...td//a[@class="remove"]`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCNLPHP3E_U

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks pretty OK, but there is no HTML code so we can just guess what happen. What about the number **8**?

Try to use XPath axes. For example locator could look like this:

```
//table[@id='tableTest']/tbody/tr[1]/descendant::a[@class="remove"]
```

This should find the remove button in the 1st row whenewer it is.

Answer (score 0):

Click the button of the first line... which I think you mean first row?

`//table[@id='tableTest']/tbody/tr//a[@class="remove"]`

That SHOULD find the first tr (row) of your table and select the href with the class remove. But it's not going to ensure it's the last cell, which if that's vital you'll need to use something like `//table[@id='tableTest']/tbody/tr/td[last()]/a[@class="remove"]`

Also, if you attach the html snippet this becomes much easier for many of us to answer.